# Проблема с проверкой элемента в hashset

Tags: java, коллекции, hashset

Есть некоторый менеджер книг на полке. Есть коллекция книг Hashset.
Есть метод быстрого поиска выполненный через contains.

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Book {
    private String name;
    private String writer;
    private int isbn;

    Book(  String name, String writer, int serial) {
        this.name = name;
        this.writer = writer;
        this.isbn = serial;
    }

    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setWriter(String writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getWriter() {
        return writer;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Автор '" + name + '\'' +
                ", наименование книги: " +"' "+ writer + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Book book = (Book) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, book.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}

BookCase.java


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class BookCase {
    HashSet<Book> books;


    BookCase() {
        books = new HashSet<>();  //ArrayList<>();
    }

    void addBook(String bookName, String author, int serial) {
        Book book = new Book(bookName, author, serial);
        books.add(book);

    }

    HashSet<Book> showBooks() {
        System.out.println("Список книг: ");
        return books;
    }

    ArrayList<Book> findBook(String input) {
        ArrayList<Book> findBookList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Book book : books) {
            if ((input.equals(book.getName())) | (input.equals(book.getWriter()))) {
                findBookList.add(book);
            }
        }
        return findBookList;
    }

    void showBookInfo(String input) {
        ArrayList<Book> showInfoBook = findBook(input);
        for (Book book : showInfoBook) {
            System.out.println("Название книги: " + book.getName() + " Писатель: " + book.getWriter());
        }
    }

    void delBook(String input) {
        for (Book book : books) {
            if ((input.equals(book.getName())) | (input.equals(book.getWriter()))) {
                books.remove(book);
                System.out.println("Книга удалена");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Нет такой книги.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    boolean checkBookInSet(String name) {                 //<<<------ метод быстрого поиска 
        return books.contains(name.hashCode());
    }

    Book fastSearch(String soughtForBook) {
        if (checkBookInSet(soughtForBook)) {
            for (Book book : books) {
                if (book.equals(soughtForBook)) {         //<<<------- проверка соответствия
                    return book;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Такого нет");
        }
        return null;
    }


}

Main.java

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BookCase bookCase = new BookCase();
        bookCase.addBook("пушкин","сказки", 111);
        bookCase.addBook("непушкин","несказки",222);
        bookCase.addBook("гоголь","нос",333);
        bookCase.addBook("прямая линия", "pooteen", 2020);
        Menu menu = new Menu(bookCase);
        menu.offerMenu();
    }
}


Menu.java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {
    Scanner scanner;
    BookCase bookCase;

    public Menu(BookCase bookCase) {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.bookCase = bookCase;
    }

    void offerMenu() {
        int userInput;
        do {
            listOptions();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Выберите опцию:");
            System.out.println();
            userInput = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            processing(userInput);
        }
        while (userInput() != 7);
        System.out.println("Работа завершена.");
    }

    int userInput() {
        int userInput;

        while (true) {
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                userInput = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.nextLine();
                break;
            } else {
                scanner.nextLine();

            }
        }
        return userInput;
    }

    void listOptions() {
        System.out.println("Выберите опцию менеджера книг: ");
        System.out.println("1 - посмотреть список книг");
        System.out.println("2 - поиск книги");
        System.out.println("3 - информация по книге");
        System.out.println("4 - добавить книгу");
        System.out.println("5 - удалить книгу");
        System.out.println("6 - fast find book");
        System.out.println("0 - для выхода в основное меню");
        System.out.println("7 - выход");
    }


    private void processing(int userInput) {

        switch (userInput) {
            case 1:
                menuShowBooks();
                break;
            case 2:
                menuFindBook();
                break;
            case 3:
                bookInfo();
                break;
            case 4:
                menuAddBook();
                break;
            case 5:
                menuDelBook();
                break;
            case 6:
                menuFastFindBook();
                break;
            case 0:
                break;
            case 7:
                return;
        }
    }

    private void menuFastFindBook() {
            System.out.println("Введите название/автора книги для поиска: ");
            String bookName = scanner.nextLine();
            bookCase.fastSearch(bookName);
    }

    void bookInfo() {
        System.out.println("Введите название/автора книги для поиска: ");
        String bookName = scanner.nextLine();
        bookCase.showBookInfo(bookName);
    }

    void menuFindBook() {
        System.out.println("Введите название/автора книги для поиска: ");
        String bookName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(bookCase.findBook(bookName));
    }


    void menuShowBooks() {
        for (Book book : bookCase.books) {
            System.out.println(book);
        }
    }

    void menuAddBook() {
        System.out.println("Введите автора: ");
        String bookName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите название:");
        String author = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите серийник:");
        int serial = scanner.nextInt();
        bookCase.addBook(bookName, author, serial);
        System.out.println("Добавлено в библиотЭку");
    }

    void menuDelBook() {
        System.out.println("Введите название/автора книги для удаления: ");
        String bookName = scanner.nextLine();
        bookCase.delBook(bookName);
    }
}
```

**Посмотрел видео - не понял, почитал книгу - не понял.**

Вопросы:

1. В методе поиска boolean checkBookInSet(String name) {
   правильно ли выполнена проверка
   books.contains(name.hashCode()); ?
   Трассировка показывает хэш входящей величины, но я не увидел хэш экземпляра коллекции.
   Что я не сделал, не так понял, не доделал ?
2. Будет ли работать проверка соответствия искомой книги, книге в коллекции
   if (book.equals(soughtForBook)) {
   если в конструкторе книги **ТРИ** поля, а в equals проверяется только **ОДНО** ?

Comment: 1) HashSet для поиска предназначен для книг. Соответсвенно, искать в нем надо книгу, а не `name.hashCode()`\

Comment: 2) Код будет работать так, как вы его напишете. Если вы не учитываете поля в equals и hashCode функциях, то они не будут учитываться при поиске в HashSet

Comment: Сбросьте ссылку на книгу и на видео. В этой задаче требуется исправить ошибки кодирования, после исправления синтаксических ошибок. Поэтому вопрос правильно ли написан код является излишним. Переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы было понятно где вы видите ошибку, и что вы понимаете как должна работать программа. Чего вы хотите добиться и как вы пытались исправить ошибки в коде. Что не получилось?

Answer (score 4):

Как по мне , то здесь проблема другого рода: очень странно заталкивать объект в хешированную коллекцию, при этом считать хеш и сравнивать объект по одному полю. Проблема не в том, что это не будет работать, а в том, что существует понятие ожидаемого поведения инженерной системы. Это примерно тоже самое, что перебрать все элементы коллекции, запустив цикл в обратном порядке. Вы имеете аналогичный результат, но когда на него смотрят другие люди, то пытаются понять, почему вы решили осуществить перебор именно в обратном порядке? В итоге бессмысленно потраченное время для осознание странного решения. Здесь все еще хуже. Есть сет, предполагающий хранение уникальных элементов. Это ожидаемое поведение системы. Теперь я добавляю книгу с одинаковым названием, но разными номерами и автором. Это разные объекты, ведь книги по сути разные. Я ожидаю , что сет добавит новый объект, т.к. такой книги еще нет и долго нахожусь в недоумении, почему у меня из сета исчезают книги (с одинаковым названием). Хотите искать по имени - сделайте map, а точнее то, что называется multimap, т.к. названия книг могут совпадать. Проблема решится сама собой. Разумеется, это не лучшее решение, но на много лучше, чем переопределять equals, hashcode так, как сделали вы.

Кроме того, очень рекомендую прочесть про SOLID, GRASP, а также не пренебрегать инкапсуляцией (не даром это принцип ООП !!!). Определите ответственность своих классов и методов. Как минимум, станет очевидно, что нет смысла иметь класс  Menu с набором методов, задача которых сводится к вызову аналогичных методов класса BookCase. Я бы еще мог понять, если бы методы BookCase ничего не выводили в консоль, но увы... Помните про принцип KISS, меньшее количество простого кода всегда читается проще и работает лучше! Да и дублирующие друг-друга по логике исполнения методы в функционале вашей программы не добавляют ясности. Попробуйте примерно так:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class BookCase {

    private final Set<Book> books;

    public BookCase() {
        books = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public boolean addBook(String bookName, String author, int serial) {
        return books.add(new Book(bookName, author, serial));
    }

    public int delBook(String input) {
        int size = books.size();
        books.removeAll(find(input));
        return size - books.size();
    }

    public Set<Book> findBook(String input) {
        return find(input);
    }

    private Set<Book> find(String arg) {
        if (arg == null || arg.trim().isEmpty()) return books;
        else return books.stream()
                    .filter(book -> arg.equals(book.getName()) || arg.equals(book.getWriter()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    
    @lombok.Value
    private static class Book {

        private String name;
        private String writer;
        private int isbn;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Автор '" + name + '\''
                    + ", наименование книги: " + "' " + writer + '\''
                    + '}';
        }

    }

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {

    private final Scanner scanner;
    private final BookCase bookCase;

    public Menu() {
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.bookCase = new BookCase();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        
        menu.bookCase.addBook("пушкин", "сказки", 111);
        menu.bookCase.addBook("непушкин", "несказки", 222);
        menu.bookCase.addBook("гоголь", "нос", 333);
        menu.bookCase.addBook("прямая линия", "pooteen", 2020);
        
        menu.offerMenu();
    }

    public void offerMenu() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Выберите опцию менеджера книг: ");
            System.out.println("1 - посмотреть список книг");
            System.out.println("2 - поиск книги");
            System.out.println("3 - добавить книгу");
            System.out.println("4 - удалить книгу");
            System.out.println("0 - выход");
            System.out.println("Выберите опцию:");
            if (processing(userInputInt()) == 0) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Работа завершена.");
    }

    private int userInputInt() {
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine().trim());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private int processing(int userInput) {
        switch (userInput) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Список книг: " + bookCase.findBook(null));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Введите название/автора книги для поиска: ");
                System.out.println(bookCase.findBook(scanner.nextLine()));
                break;
            case 3:
                menuAddBook();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Введите название/автора книги для удаления: ");
                System.out.println("Удалено книг : " + bookCase.delBook(scanner.nextLine()));
                break;
        }
        return userInput;
    }

    private void menuAddBook() {
        System.out.println("Введите автора: ");
        String bookName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите название:");
        String author = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите серийник:");
        int serial = userInputInt();
        if (serial==-1){
            System.out.println("Некорреткный серийник!");
            return;
        }
        bookCase.addBook(bookName, author, serial);
        System.out.println("Добавлено в библиотЭку");
    }

}
```